# github find list of all changes been made since certain day in a branch

Tags: git, github

In github, how could I find out all the changes been made to a branch since given time? I need the output of the list as well. I played with github, but I didn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`git whatchanged`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged)

Example:

```
git whatchanged --since="2 weeks ago" <branch>
```

Comment: instead of "2 weeks ago", what's for "since July 15"?

Comment: You can specify date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format. Ex `git whatchanged --since="7/1/2015" <branch>`